# Issues with LB_GETCURSEL

Tags: c, winapi

I am having some issues with `lb_getcursel` and what it returns (if it does even return anything)

heres my message handler...

```
case IDT_TESTLIST1:
if(HIWORD(wParam) == LBN_DBLCLK) {
    int ret = 0;
    double TimeOut = 60.0;
    int Lng = 1;
    unsigned char Param[255] = {0};
    unsigned char Port1 = port1;

    int iCurSel = SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd,IDT_TESTLIST1,LB_GETCURSEL,0.0);

    ret = PSB30_Open(Port1,16);
    ret = PSB30_SendOrder(Port1,test1[iCurSel].testNumber, &Param[0],&Lng,&TimeOut);
    ret = PSB30_Close(Port1);
}
break;
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and whenever i run the program iCurSel doesn't look like it even gets assigned a value, defaults to 0, when i step into the case statement, not all variables are visible in the autos section, when i add a watch to iCurSel i get a CXX0017: Error message.

hwnd is the handle to my main window and is correct

any help would be appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Is the list box single-selection? If not you'll get LB_ERR (-1) returned.

Comment: Sorry yes, it is single-selection. WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|LBS_NOTIFY

Comment: If you put a breakpoint after assigning `iCurSel` what does it contain?

Comment: Nothing, either by hovering over the variable or the autos/watch windows

Comment: This is a Debug build?

Comment: yeah it is, i'm totally confused by this one, beginning to think its visual studio thats playing up

Comment: Sounds strange - I would rebuild all and double check that your debug command is not running a different exe from the build. I can't see any code problem.

Comment: rebuilt all and when checking i have a debug build and a release build, is this right or should i have just the 1 build? Relatively new to visual studio

Comment: Make sure your build configuration is set to Debug, delete the Release exe just in case, set a breakpoint and press F5 to run.

Comment: did all that still the same, i find it funny that none of my variables in the message are showing anything by hovering over them, possibly something wrong elsewhere :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i find it funny that none of my variables in the message are showing anything by hovering over them

That's because *they don't exist*.  Your program cannot compile, it has an error.  SendDlgItemMessage() takes 5 arguments, you pass 4.  The last one got morphed into a floating point value by a typo.

Clearly you'll need to pay attention to compile error messages.  And change a setting so this cannot happen again.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solution, Build and Run.  Change the "On Run, when build or deployment error occurs" setting to "Do not launch".

Comment: hmmm sorry about that, thats a typo, it should be 0,0, my development machine is different from this one so i mistakingly hand typed it in

Comment: accepted this because during the night i discovered that the issue was outwith the message handler and was caused by my struct not holding the correct information, basically every entry in .testNumber was set to 0.